# Radix Sort. Why is array traversed from end?

Tags: arrays, sorting, visual-c++, c++14

```
void countingsort(int arr[], int n, int exp)
{   

    int count[10] = {0};
    int* output = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]++;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)//Why is array traversed from end?
    {
        output[count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10] - 1] = arr[i];
        count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = output[i];
}

void radixsort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int m = getMax(arr, n);
    for (int exp = 1; m / exp > 0; exp *= 10)
        countingsort(arr, n, exp);
}
```

In the counting sort function i do not understand why the count array is being traversed from the end ? What difference would it make if we traversed it from the beginning ?

Comment: Have you tried traversing it the other way around to see what happens? Also you have a horrible memory leak.

Comment: Yeah i did traverse the other way round. When the countsort function is called the second time for exp = 10 the for loop in question never ends. The value of i never gets updated and i dont understand why. And yes i know i forgot to delete output.

Comment: For each digit `d`, `count[d]` indicates the *last* unused position in the `d`th bucket (well, one past the last, to be precise). Each bucket is being filled right to left, end to start (note how, inside the loop, `count[d]` is decremented rather than incremented). For that reason, previously partially sorted data needs to be visited backwards, so as to preserve previously established partial order.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I do not understand why the buckets need to be filled from end to start and how it will preserve previously established partial order.

Comment: They don't need to be. The implementor chose them to be. One of the answers below shows an alternative implementation were they are filled start to end. As to previously established order - that's the central idea of radix sort. You first group and order numbers by the least significant digit. Then you group and order them by second least significant digit - but within each group, you preserve the order established on the first pass, so that, say, `12` comes ahead of `15`. And so on, all the way to the most significant digit, whereupon the array would end up fully sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The array is traversed backwards because the counts are converted into ending indices. Example where the counts are converted into starting indices and the array is traversed forwards:

```
void countingsort(int arr[], int n, int exp)
{   
    int count[10] = {0};
    int* output = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]++;
    int sum = 0, tmp;               // convert counts to starting indices
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        tmp = count[i];
        count[i] = sum;
        sum += tmp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)    // traverse from beginning
    {
        output[count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]] = arr[i];
        count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]++;   // -- => ++
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = output[i];
    delete[] output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say, for a particular key `K` you have it occurring at positions

```
..., u, ..., v, ..., w, ...
```

after counting, you determine that these elements go to positions

```
..., count[K]-2, count[K]-1, count[K], ...
```

and you store them in order `count[K]`, `count[K]-1`, `count[K]-2`

To obtain the property that the `countingsort` is *stable* (so it preserves the ordering, established by previous calls to `countingsort`), you have to store the elements in order `w`, `v`, `u`, i.e. have to traverse the array backwards.

Comment: But what will happen if i traverse the array forwards ? How will it disturb the previously established order is what im trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this input : [643, 613]

after working with 2nd digit (from right) array becomes [613,643]

so while working with 3rd digit (from right) if we traverse forward direction
we will put 613 in position 1 (as count[] indicates end indices)

**Bottom line** : Array is already sorted based on previous digits...so traversing
order matters while considering current digit